# Puppeteer driven headless chromium closing immediately in Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, chromium, puppeteer

I'm trying to automate some form submission using puppeteer on my raspberry pi 4 (4gb RAM) and I'm having some weird issues. My full script works perfectly with `headless: false`, but when I try to run the script in headless mode I start running into trouble.

The following script **works**:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com')
  var title = await page.title();
  console.log(title)
  browser.close()
})();
```

But if I try to run a slightly more complex script (i.e. do something useful after opening the page), it seems that headless browser closes. So for instance this script **fails**:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com')
  await page.waitForSelector('input');
  await page.type('input', 'test@example.com')
  var title = await page.title();
  console.log(title)
  browser.close()
})();
```

I start getting errors like:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed`

- NodeJS Version:`v10.16.3`
- NPM Version: `6.9.0`
- Chromium Browser version: `Chromium 74.0.3729.157 Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 10`
- Puppeteer Version: `1.20.0`

Thanks!

Comment: Can you debug and find out where exactly does it stop and fails? goto/waitForSelector/type('input'.."/...etc?

Comment: @laggingrefelx Most of the times it fails at `await page.waitForSelector('input');`

Comment: It may be redirecting. Try [waitForNavigation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) (notice the example given there carefully, it's important to create the promise before any action).

Comment: Also checkout [waitUntil](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#framegotourl-options) option for `goto`, try "networkidle2"

Comment: have you found any fix to this  ? @AnthonySilva

Comment: @AswinAshad nope!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably closing the browser too soon. It should be

```
await browser.close()
```

Comment: Just tried that, still getting: 

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed`